# How to exit an windows application in a safe and complete way

Tags: vb.net

I have a windows forms application with 10 forms.

Form1 is the startup form and bears the username and password boxes for the user to login to Form4.

Form4 contains buttonslinks to all the other forms.

I have set the Form_Closed events for Form5,6,7,8,9 & 10 to open Form4. I.e.

```
Private Sub Form5_FormClosed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
    Form4.Show()
End Sub 'Back to Main Menu
```

The Form4_Closed event opens Form1 and the Form1_Closed event Exits application.

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
    Application.Exit()
End Sub
```

**Question 1.** Why is it that after I close Form1 the application is still running At the windows Task manager processes and is preventing the user from shutting down a computer.

**Question 2.** Is my navigation across the app affecting the system memory?

Comment: If you got rid of Form1_FormClosed all together, would this solve your problem?  How is the user closing Form1?  A button? x-ing out?  Do you have code in any other handlers that tries to close Form1?

Comment: What happens when you debug it, does it close and return to Visual Studio or is it stuck there too? If one of the forms set `e.Cancel` to `True` in their FormClosing event the application won't close, even though you use `Application.Exit()`.

Comment: @Dustin, they are x-ing out. Lemmi try to get rid of Form1_FormClosed I'll let u know.

Comment: @Vincent all going nice and smooth when I am debugging. Where is this e.Cancel located. Could be there is one, maybe i check across all the forms.

Comment: Just check all `FormClosing` events, if one of them contains `e.Cancel = True` then it's probably what's causing the issue. It could be due to an exception when a form is about to close too.

Comment: @Vincent. Are we talking of Form_Closing or Form_Closed? Because in my case i have used Form_Closed all through.

Comment: Have you changed the value of the Shutdown Mode in the project properties? [How to: Specify Shutdown Behavior for an Application (Visual Basic)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hzfysdc%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)